# find all the patients associated to a specific medical_center without nested routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am using rails4 and ruby2. I have two models: MedicalCenter and patient. Medical center has many patients. I have not nested their routes. Please help me to find all the patients of a specific `medical_center_id` and display it in medical center's show action.

```
class MedicalCentersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_medical_center, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :require_signin!

def index
@medical_centers = MedicalCenter.all
end

def show
@patients=Patient.find(:all, :conditions => ["medical_center_id = ?", params[:medical_center_id]])
end

def new
@medical_center = MedicalCenter.new
end

def edit
end

def create
@medical_center = MedicalCenter.new(medical_center_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @medical_center.save
    format.html { redirect_to @medical_center, notice: 'Medical center was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @medical_center }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @medical_center.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end


private
def set_medical_center
  @medical_center = MedicalCenter.find(params[:id])
end
def medical_center_params
  params.require(:medical_center).permit(:name, :address, :phone_no)
end
end
```

show.html.erb of `MedicalCenter class`

```
Associated patients:
<% @patients.each do |s| %>
  <ul>
<li><%=link_to s.name, patient_path(s)%></li>
  </ul>
<%end%>

 routes.rb
  resources :medical_centers
  resources :patients
```

Right now it shows blank when I go to the show action of a medical center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `show method` of your `MedicalCentersController` like this

```
def show
@patients = Patient.find(:all, :conditions => ["medical_center_id = ?",@medical_center.id])
end
```

**Update**

If you want to put this code in your `MedicalCenter` Model,then you have to do like this

```
#medical_center.rb

def some_method_name
@med = self.find(params[:id])
@patients = Patient.find(:all, :conditions => ["medical_center_id = ?",@med.id])
end
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i implement this code in model instead of controller?

Comment: then how and where should I call "some_method_name"?

Comment: @dips Need to think! Will be answering to your question tomorrow :)